# Can static member variables be initialized via member initialization list?

Tags: c++

I tried to initialize a static member variable with a member initialization list. But I got errors like

> static variable cannot be initialized via constructor

For example, my class `sample` has a static member variable `y` of type `int`. I couldn't do this:

```
sample(int a):y(a){}
```

Why is that so?

Comment: Sorry there is no semi colon at end of the statement.

Comment: Maybe read a book to learn the basics? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Deepika If you made a mistake in your question, you can [edit] it to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A static member variable does not belong to a single instance of your class. So when a constructor (which is a function that initializes an instance) runs, the static member already is initialized. You cannot initialize it again.

You can however assign to it in the constructor's body:

```
sample(int a) {y = a;}
```

though that will rarely be useful.

Again, remember: Every time a constructor runs, it constructs one instance, while static members exist across all instances.

Answer (score 0):

A static member is per-class, not per-instance, so a static member will only be constructed once in the lifetime of the program.  A constructor is invoked every time you make an instance of the class.

What you want to do is initialize the static member inside of a .cc file that will be liked in.

Something like :

```
// Foo.h

class Bar {
    public :
       Bar(int) {
       }

};

class Foo {
  public:
         static Bar MrStatic;
};

// Foo.cc

Bar Foo::MrStatic(10);
```